# Dropzone with struts to upload files

Tags: struts, dropzone.js

With struts, the uploaded files will be saved as tmp first, how to guarantee the uploaded files are in sequence, since I have to save them with the original file names?

Comment: You have access to the filename via the file upload interceptor.

Comment: Yes, I do. But the fileUploadInterceptor doesn't call the getter and setter of filename and contentType if I upload multiple files? they only being called if I upload single file? i.e. uploadMultiple=false of dropzone

Comment: Multiple files? It's not designed for that at all; don't know it'd deal with that. But you should add that to the question since it completely changes the nature of the question.